# Doctrine Mysql JsonType Column value returns empty array despite data present

Tags: mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have Symfony application which I recently Migrated (Only Symfony packages - from 5.4 to 6.4) and one entity has a field of type object A that extends JsonType from Doctrine and is behind 2 interfaces.

Now the problem is there is correct Json in the Json type Column in MySQL but it always returns empty collection - I checked this with Xdebug and Doctrine is not even initializing object that has this JSON field...

The thing is - it works perfectly while using Symfony 5.4 packages but returns empty set if using 6.4 packages. I did not updated Doctrine - its still 2.11.

And type is JSON, not deprecated JSON_ARRAY.

Any ideas what in Symfony packages might cause this sudden change in behavior? It just returns nothing without any change in /src code.

I was expecting to get data from json colum which I checked is present in the DB and json is correcy.

I tried running entire code step by step with Xdebug and application just behaves like those values does not exist in database but they do. There is no place where there is data and is lost - from the very end there is no data fetched.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.